# Report/Delete/Edit irrelevant tag

Tags: feature-request

Recently I have found a **tag** which has **spelling mistake**

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obsever

I have tried to update it or delete it or report it, but I am unable to do any of these. There should be a way to update tags like this or report these types of tags.

Comment: Since this is about a specific tag, I recommend adding that tag to your title. Posting about faulty tags in meta seems to be common practice across several SE sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I moved all the questions to the [event-observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-observer).
It will take a while for the `obsever` tag to show now questions. (cache probably).
After a few days, tags with no questions will be automatically removed.

Comment: That's good :) But this will fix the issue for now, what if these type of tags create in future? Is there a way to report misspelled tags?

Comment: you can suggest synonyms for the misspelled tags. or your can report them just like this.